# Push dynamic SQL statement into a variable that and reuse in my script

Tags: sql-server

I don't understand why my variable ColumnList2 is empty, I want to reuse this variable in my script.

```
DECLARE @ColumnList nvarchar(max) = 
    'SELECT @ColumnListOut = STUFF(
      (SELECT
         '', '' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''s_CRM_Perms''
         AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE''AC_%''
       FOR XML PATH('''') ), 1, 1, '''' )'

DECLARE @ColumnList2 nvarchar(max)  

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @ColumnList,N'@ColumnListOut nvarchar(max) output', @ColumnListOut = @ColumnList2 OUT

DECLARE @Dynasql as varchar(max)
DECLARE @tb as varchar(512)
DECLARE @Where as varchar(max)

SET @tb = ' S_CRM_Perms'
SET @Where = ' WHERE [GroupName] = ''Guest'' '
SET @Dynasql = (' SELECT ' + @ColumnList2 + ' FROM' + @tb + @Where )

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @Dynasql
```

Comment: There is nothing dynamic about your dynamic SQL here. You could achieve this using normal variable assignment. Is there a reason you are using dynamic SQL?

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to get a list of column and push this list into another query. Thepurpose of this is to execute the second query dynamically beacause the columns can be different from a table to another.

Comment: I fully understand that, but generating the column list doesn't need to be dynamic sql, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50cf9891bb612a9adba906e5a235ac4a

Comment: Ok got it. But the second query needs to be dynamic right ? I updated my code, but still does not work.

Comment: Ok it was nvarchar instead of varchar.

Answer (score 0):

A few pieces missing in your query.  Try this:

```
DECLARE @ColumnList nvarchar(max) =  ' SELECT @ColumnListOut = STUFF(
(select
'', '' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = ''s_CRM_Perms''
and COLUMN_NAME like ''AC_%''
  FOR XML PATH('''') ), 1, 1, '''' )'

DECLARE @ColumnList2 nvarchar(max)  

EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @ColumnList,N'@ColumnListOut nvarchar(max) output', @ColumnListOut = @ColumnList2 OUT

select @ColumnList2
```